# Use http.get Node.js with callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am trying to implement this library [here](https://github.com/metafloor/bwip-js#nodejs-request-handler), which generates QR codes and all other kinds of codes.

The problem I have is making a request where I have access to both req and res object, since I will need to pass these to the library. In the documentation, they are recommending

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // If the url does not begin /?bcid= then 404.  Otherwise, we end up
    // returning 400 on requests like favicon.ico.
    if (req.url.indexOf('/?bcid=') != 0) {
        res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type':'text/plain' });
        res.end('BWIPJS: Unknown request format.', 'utf8');
    } else {
        bwipjs.request(req, res); // Executes asynchronously
    }

}).listen(3030);
```

The problem is I already have a server created, and I simply want to call the library in a get request, without creating another server. I have tried

```
http.get('http://localhost:3030/?bcid=azteccode&text=thisisthetext&format=full&scale=2', (req, res) => {
  bwipjs.request(req, res); // Executes asynchronously
  }
)
```

which obviously didn't work as the callback only takes response as an argument.

I would like to use bare node in the implementation as this is the way my server is implemented, and I don't want to add a library (like Express) just for this scenario.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are saying. Can you please be specific.

Comment: The call to the library is done like so:  bwipjs.request(req, res). Therefore, for me to make the call, I need to have access to req and res. However, in the http.get, I only have the response:

http.get(url, (response) => {
  bwipjs(request??, response)
})

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/making-http-requests-with-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

You are heavily misunderstanding the role of `http.get`

[`http.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) is used to do **HTTP GET** call to that certain url. It's basically what `axios` or `request` or `ajax` or `xhr` or `postman` or `browser` does.

The url param of `http.get` is not route. It's literally is the url you want to hit.

If you want to handle specific route you have to do it in the `http.createServer()` handler itself.

Like,

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url.indexOf('/?bcid=') != 0) {
      //do something
  } else if (req.method == "get" && req.url.indexOf('/?bcid=') != 0){
      bwipjs.request(req, res); // Executes asynchronously
  } else {
    //do something else
  }

}).listen(3030);
```

Check out the [`req` or `http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) for available properties that you can use.